# Sorting by a value from the localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I got a value set from one page, when this is saved to the `localStorage` I'm redirecting the user to another state with at list I want to sort by the value in the `localStorage`.

Example: Every entry with a score above 1000 is shown at the top of the list.
This is my load function for the list.

```
$scope.load = function () {
    if ($scope.query.page < 1) {
        $scope.query.page = 1;
    }

    localStorageService.set('schools_query', $scope.query);

    $scope.promise = $http.get('/api/schools', { params: $scope.query }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.data = resp.data;
    });
};
```

Is this possible in the frontend? Or should I do this in the backend?

Comment: Why are you using AngularJS? In any case, I'm guessing you want to display the $scope.data in your template. You can try to use orderBy pipe in the loop https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: local storage is available only of client side. Backend won't be able to reach it

Comment: @SergeyMell Saving the localStorage item to a model onSave and send this to the back-end would solve this. This is what i want to avoid.

Comment: Are you paginating on the backend? If so, you'd pretty much have to sort on the backend also...

Comment: As heretic Monkey suggests, you can't sort data you don't have, so either the sorting has to be done serverside or you will have to retrieve all data (all pages) client side before sorting (and only after you are able to tell which result will end on which page)